# App is not indexable by Google Search; consider adding at least one Activity with an ACTION-VIEW intent filter

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

Что будет если на это предупреждение не реагировать вообще?

Comment: Тоже мучает этот вопрос. Вроде сделал через firebase все как надо, но индексация не происходит и скачек нет

Comment: Ответ более глубокий на Ваш вопрос хранится [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367875/android-adding-at-least-one-activity-with-an-action-view-intent-filter-after-u)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете создавать ссылки на приложения для Android это URL-адреса HTTP, которые приводят пользователей непосредственно к определенному контенту в приложении для Android.

Ссылки на приложения для Android могут привлечь больше пользователей к вашему приложению и облегчитьим доступ к контенту внутри приложения.

Для создания ссылки необходимо настроить `<intnet-filter>`, а потом обрабатывать входящие `intent`, есть несколько очень подробных статей в оф доках:

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html

**Ответ:**  ничего не будет, кроме того что вам советует AndroidStudio.

> Ссылки на приложения для Android могут привлечь больше пользователей

Comment: Как и где эти ссылки будут работать? В поисковиках, в Google Play, Google? и т.д.

Comment: Будут индексироваться в поиске Google, не в GooglePlay

Comment: Спасибо! О, это уже становится интереснее... )))

Comment: Если вы будете делать сайт для приложения или наоборот, считаю что это очень полезная фича.

Comment: Shwarz Andrei! Спасибо Вам! Вы мне реально помогли, и думаю, не только мне... )

Comment: Все равно не пойму толком что и куда добавлять... Хоть один пример бы был простой

Comment: Я так понимаю это будет работать только если есть свой сайт или со своей страницы в соц. сетях?

Comment: А как избавиться от жёлтого поля который мешает нормально смотреть на Манифест.
Или они специально добавили эту херню с ссылками. Раньше её не было , всё норм было.

Comment: @Stanislav это LINT вы можете поставить марк аннотацию игнорировать это (Alt + enter) или отключить в настройках.